# Using two WHERE statements for different tables

Tags: php, sql, pdo, twitter-follow

I have build a follow system but that system displays all members who are even temporarily deactivated, for disabling deactivated members from showing in areas such as followers or following I have added a column 'closed' in members table which is initially set to `no` and when a member wants to temporarily deactivate his profile this no is updated to yes. Now my idea is to join the `select` statement which selects members followed or following from `follow` table with members with the column `closed` set to `no` in `members` table so my system displays only activated members.

My select statement is:

```
SELECT * FROM follow WHERE uid=:memberid
```

I tried but get syntax error for this:

```
SELECT * FROM follow INNER JOIN members on members.memberid=follow.uid WHERE uid=:memberidid WHERE closed=no
```

Comment: You don't need multiple WHEREs. Just use the "and" operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `WHERE` twice, you can use `AND` for the 'second' `WHERE`-clause.

```
SELECT * FROM `follow` INNER JOIN `members` ON `members`.`memberid` = `follow`.`uid` WHERE `uid` = :memberidid AND `closed` = "no"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM 
follow INNER JOIN members 
on members.memberid=follow.uid 
WHERE follow.uid=follow.memberid 
AND members.closed='no'
```